# Using Unity Framework & Validation Application Block to Validate Method Parameters

Tags: c#, validation, unity-container, enterprise-library, validation-application-bl

### Question

Is it posible to have the `Validation.Validate()` method of the Validation Application Block see each parameter of the `IParameterCollection` supplied by Unity as my custom `UserModel`?

---

### Background:

I am attempting to use both Unity and the Validation Application Block to validate method parameters.

I would like to be able to denote a method as `[RequiresValidation()]` and the parameters of that method with the appropriate validation attributes.

So, something like this:

```
[RequiresValidation()]
public void SaveUser(UserModel user)
{
  // ...
}

public class UserModel
{
  [StringLengthValidator(3, 255)]
  [RegexValidator(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]${3,255}")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [StringLengthValidator(0, 255)]
  [RegexValidator(@"\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b")]
  public string EMail { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a custom HandlerAttribute that will initiate the call to the validation handler as shown.

```
public class RequiresValidationAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
  public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
  {
    return new ValidationCallHandler();
  }
}
```

Now, the Validation Handler will attempt to validate each parameter of the method:

```
public class ValidationCallHandler : ICallHandler
{
  public int Order { get; set; }

  public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
  {            
    // Validate the method parameters
    ValidateArguments(input.Arguments);

    // Call the method that was intercepted
    return getNext()(input, getNext);
  }

  private static void ValidateArguments(IParameterCollection parameterCollection)
  {
    foreach (var parameter in parameterCollection)
    {
      var results = Validation.Validate(parameter);
      if (results.IsValid) continue;

      // ...
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

### Problem

The `Validation.Validate()` method will always return **true**.  Based on my observations, it seems the validation logic is treating the `parameter` as an `object` and not my `UserModel`.

---

### Question

Is it posible to have the `Validation.Validate()` method of the Validation Application Block see each parameter of the `IParameterCollection` supplied by Unity as my custom `UserModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the `ValidationFactory` instead of the `Validation` class. When you replace this line:

```
var results = Validation.Validate(parameter);
```

With the following line, you can get it to work.

```
var results =
    ValidationFactory.CreatValidator(parameter.GetType())
        .Validate(parameter);
```

Good luck.

Comment: I just gave this a try and it worked perfectly.  Much appreciated.  Thank You.